# div width adjusting to 100% if another div is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I set the width of `#leftdiv` to 100% when `#rightdiv` is hidden, and when the button is clicked, both `<div>`s should be next to each other.

I already got both `<div>`s next to each other on the button click, but I wanted to expand `#leftdiv` to 100% when `#rightdiv` is hidden.

```js
function toggleSideBar() {  
    var div = document.getElementById('rightdiv');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }  
};
```

```css
#leftdiv
{
   border: solid medium thick;
   float: left;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #ffc;
   /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

#rightdiv
{
   width: 50%;
   border: solid medium thick;
   background-color: #ffa;
   display: none;
   float:right;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="toggle" onclick="toggleSideBar()" />
    <div id="main-content">
        <div id="leftdiv">selectable</div>
        <div id="rightdiv">right panel</div>
    </div>`
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use flex box for this:

`HTML`

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="toggle" onclick="toggleSideBar()" />
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="leftdiv">selectable</div>
  <div id="rightdiv">right panel</div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
#main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

#leftdiv {
  background-color: #ffc;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#rightdiv {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #ffa;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

`JS`

```
function toggleSideBar() {  
    var div = document.getElementById('rightdiv');

    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

The main reason your example did not work as you wanted is the use of `float`.
Floating causes an element to only occupy the space needed by its content.
Using float, you have to use `width:100%` for the left container to fix this.
To make it switch dynamically from 50% to 100% width it would also be necessary to switch the style between those two in your toggle function.

With flexbox all of this is no longer necessary as its children get ordered automatically by the direction you want, in this case as a row. Setting `flex: 1 1 auto;` for both containers makes them grow and shrink equally to occupy all the space they can get. (`flex: 1 0 auto;` would also work here, as the shrinking behavior does not make any difference in this example.)

Answer (score 0):

something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/nw8Ln6ha/18/

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="toggle" onclick="toggleSideBar()" />
<div id="main-content">
   <div id="leftdiv">selectable</div>
   <div id="rightdiv">right panel</div>
</div>
<script>
  function toggleSideBar() {

    var r_div = document.getElementById('rightdiv');
    var l_div = document.getElementById('leftdiv');
    if (r_div.style.display !== 'none') {
        r_div.style.display = 'none';
        l_div.setAttribute('style', '');
    }
    else {
        r_div.style.display = 'block';
        l_div.setAttribute('style', '30%');
    }

};
</script>
```

**css**

```
#leftdiv
{

  border: solid medium thick;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffc;
 /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  width: 100%;

}

#rightdiv
{

 width: 50%;
 border: solid medium thick;
 background-color: #ffa;
 display: block;
 float:right;

}
```

Comment: This does not get the desired effect the div does not start at full width.

Comment: thank you for update. But there's a issue with toggle button, it's also moving with div's

Answer (score 0):

It works without manipulating the width via JavaScript if you format them as `table-cell`s:

```js
function toggleSideBar() {
    var div = document.getElementById('rightdiv');
 if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
     div.style.display = 'none';
 } else {
  div.style.display = 'table-cell';
 } 
};
```

```css
#leftdiv {
 border: solid medium thick;
    width: auto;
 display: table-cell;
    background-color: #ffc;
}

#rightdiv {
    width: 50%;
    border: solid medium thick;
    background-color: #ffa;
    display: none;
}

#main-content {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="toggle" onclick="toggleSideBar()" />
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="leftdiv">selectable</div>
    <div id="rightdiv">right panel</div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="toggle" onclick="toggleSideBar()" />
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="leftdiv">selectable</div>
    <div id="rightdiv">right panel</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#leftdiv
{
   border: solid medium thick;
   float: left;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #ffc;
   height:50px;
   width: 50%;
   /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

#rightdiv
{
   width: 50%;
   height:50px;
   border: solid medium thick;
   background-color: #ffa;
   display: none;
   float:right;
}
```

**JS**

```
function toggleSideBar() {
    debugger;
    var div = document.getElementById('rightdiv');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('leftdiv').style.width = '100%';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
 document.getElementById('leftdiv').style.width = '';
    }

};
```

you can also check running example of this code on :

[http://jsfiddle.net/zjea48bu/19/](https://jsfiddle.net/zjea48bu/19/)